Number of re-renders in React
As mentioned in React documentation page, that React batches state updates in queues so that it prevents it from too many re-renders. Does setTimeout in state updates hinders this functionality. If so how does React processes the state updates and how does it queue those in batches.
import { useRef, useState } from 'react';
export default function App() {
  const thirdCatRef = useRef(null);
  const [status1, setStatus1] = useState(false);
  const [status2, setStatus2] = useState(false);
  const [status3, setStatus3] = useState(false);
  const renders = useRef(0);
  renders.current+=1;
    function handleClick()
        {
            setTimeout(()=> setStatus1(true),2000);
            setTimeout(()=>setStatus2(true),5000);
            setStatus3(true);
        }
 
  return (
<>
    <p>No. of renders: {renders.current}</p>
<button onClick={handleClick}>
          Re-render
</button>
</>
  );
}

As of my understanding since React batches state updates in a queue, all the state updates in a single event handler will be queued and a final render will take place after all the state updates are done for that batch(here after 5 second). So the final count of renders should be 2.
But as evident from the output which is 4, React renders the component after three setState functions. So what rule does React actually follows while batching state updates in queue and rendering them?

Batching means that sequential status changes render only once. So setStatus1(); setStatus2(); would render only once instead of twice. But obviously it won't stop the entire app from rendering just because a state change is coming up several seconds later (and it wouldn't even have any way of knowing that's the case.)

Got it. But as you said at last that it won't even know, but as mentioned in the documentation " React waits until all code in the event handlers has run before processing your state updates."

All code in the event handler runs the moment the function is called. Two lines start a timer, and one line sets the state. It doesn't say that it waits until all callbacks and asynchronous calls defined in the function have fully finished and run to completion

Only the functions that cause a re-render are batched. setTimeout doesn't cause a re-render by itself, it's the callback inside the setTimeout that has the function that causes a re-render of the App component. This post explains it well.
